# Получение ответа от браузера

Tags: c#, https, webbrowser, response, fiddler

Необходимо получить данные от браузера, а точнее код авторизации. Я использую `API` ссылку для этого кода `OAuth2` сервиса `MailRu`. Этот код отображается в адресной строке браузера после успешной авторизации, при этом происходит перенаправление на `redirect_uri=...`. Для запуска браузера используется `Process`, после этого я пытаюсь прослушать порт `XXXX` с помощью `HttpListener`, однако даже если я получаю какой-то ответ, то это бессмысленный набор символов. (`UTF-8` и т.п. пробовал, результат тот же)

Как можно получить код авторизации из браузера после успешной авторизации?

## Код с использованием `HttpListener`

```
static void SniffPort()
{
    byte[] input = new byte[] { 1 };
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
    socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 5000));
    socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, input, null);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int len = socket.Receive(buffer);
            if (len <= 40) continue;
            string bin = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, 0, len);
            Console.WriteLine(bin);
        }
    });
}

static HttpListener _httpListener = new HttpListener();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting server...");
    _httpListener.Prefixes.Add("https://localhost:5000/");
    _httpListener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Server started.");
    SniffPort();

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\chrome-win\chrome.exe");
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    Process p = new Process();
    startInfo.Arguments = "--app=https://o2.mail.ru/login?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&scope=userinfo&redirect_uri=https://localhost:5000/&state=some_state";
    p.StartInfo = startInfo;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

Также был вариант с `FiddlerCore`, однако после его использования приходится изменять настройки связанные с прокси в `inetcpl.cpl`. Также это не работает если браузер запомнил пользователя и сразу авторизовался после запуска браузера, `FiddlerCore` не выдаёт эту информацию.

## Код с использованием `FiddlerCore`

```
public class HttpProxy : IDisposable
{
    public HttpProxy()
    {
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest;
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(5000, true, false);
    }

    void FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest(Fiddler.Session oSession)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("REQ: {0}", oSession.url));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
    }
}

static HttpListener _httpListener = new HttpListener();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpProxy httpProxy = new HttpProxy();
    
    //Запуск браузера как в коде, который находится выше.
}
```

Comment: соединение зашифровано? HTTPS?

Comment: @aepot, да. Если это связано с этим, как получить данные в нормальном виде в случае с `HttpListener`?

Comment: Надо знать для расшифровки приватный ключ браузера, созданный конкретно для этого соединения. Ну либо задача сводится к взлому TLS. Другими словами, никак. На то оно и шифрование, чтобы никто посторонний не мог расшифровать.

Comment: @aepot, мой подход к этой задаче является верным или существуют другие способы?

Comment: Ну я бы смотрел в сторону встроенных управляемых браузеров типа WebView2 или CefSharp, или даже эмуляции AngleSharp.JS. А так с вашим подходом я слабо знаком, не могу оценить правильность.

Comment: @aepot, `Google` отказался от поддержки embedded browser'ов. `CefSharp` и `WebView2` не работают.

Comment: У гугла есть API потому что.